# insert div at top of page without overlaying using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, overlay

I wonder if anyone can help me please ?

Basically I have a snippet of Javascript that I want to be able to give people.  So the following is true :

I can't control wherabouts in the page they decide to put the snippet (for various reasons) - It could be in the middle, the end,  wherever.

All the snippet does is put a small DIV at the top of their page.  At the moment I am doing the following (this is the snippet):

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 999; width: 100%; height: 40px; background-color:red; text-align:center; color:white"><br>Message Inside Div</div>
<script>if (Condition) { document.getElementById("mydiv").style.display = "block"; }</script>
```

Now, that works a treat and when "Condition" is true,  it shows the div.  However,  using this method it overlays the div with it fixed to the top of the page.

However,  I also want to do it so that the div is inserted at the top of the page but scrolls with the page as normal and DOESN'T overlay the content at the top (IE: It pushes the content down when it appears).

Any ideas on how I would do that please,  remember :  I don't have any access to their page (I don't even know what else is on the page) and the snippet I give them could go anywhere on the page.

Comment: I guess you'd either want to wrap the whole content body into another holder with a top margin or change the body style directly via javascript and add a margin on top that matches your div's height.

Comment: Thanks rita - THe top margin body style would work but I don't want to really do that in case they already have that set for other reasons.

What would be ideal would be to insert my div directly after the opening body tag but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can't avoid meddling with the existing code and stylings - but in case you're worried about existing top-margins on body, just check for this value first. ie. get the body top margin value, add your elements height, reapply. Example in jquery syntax (out of simplicity, can do the same in vanilla javascript)

```
$('body').css('margin-top',$('body').css('margin-top') + yourdiv-height);
```

Comment: That would work perfectly but I can't guarantee that jquery is loaded on the page.  How would I do this in vanilla Javascript please ?

I have tried this but it doesn't work :

    

var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; body.style.marginTop=body.style.marginTop+40;

Comment: I have sorted it - changed to :    body.style.marginTop=body.style.marginTop+40+"px";  and it works great :)